# React Navigation rendering inside protected Routes

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-context

after Successfully making a login page and navigating to the home page I am having a problem wrapping it with a navigation component to help me navigate various links at the home page but I am not able to see the navigation. The home page renders an empty web page. help create navigation at the homepage

This is my App.js Code

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import SignIn from './Components/SignIn';
import SignUp from './Components/SignUp';
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import { UserAuthContextProvider } from './Context/userAuthContext';
import ProtectedRoutes from './Components/ProtectedRoutes';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import Navigation from './Layout/Navigation';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
              <ToastContainer/>
              <UserAuthContextProvider> 
                  <Routes>
                      <Route  path='/home' element={<ProtectedRoutes>
                        
                           <Navigation>
                                <Home /> 
                            </Navigation>
                         
                      
                      </ProtectedRoutes>} />

                      <Route  path='/' element={ <SignIn />} />
                      <Route  path='/signup' element={ <SignUp />} />
                  </Routes>
                </UserAuthContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my Navigation component code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useUserAuthContext } from '../Context/userAuthContext';
import classes from './navigation.module.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



const Navigation = () => {

   const { LogOut } = useUserAuthContext();

   const handleSignOut = async ()=>{
     try {
       await LogOut();

     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        
     }
   }



  return (
       <header className={classes.header}>
           <h2>Bonny Electronics</h2>
          <nav>
             <ul>
                <Link><li>Home</li></Link>
                <Link><li>Records</li></Link>
                <Link><li>Book-New</li></Link>
                 <Button variant='primary' onClick={handleSignOut}>SignOut</Button>
             </ul>
              
          </nav>
       </header>
  )
}

export default Navigation;
```

My Protected Route Component codes

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useUserAuthContext } from '../Context/userAuthContext';


const ProtectedRoutes = ({ children }) => {

    let {user} = useUserAuthContext();
    if (!user){

       return <Navigate to='/' />

    }
    return children;
}

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Comment: post your `ProtectedRoutes` component.

Comment: I have made an edit to my post check it out.

Comment: Two things you should try: 1) `Navigation` should also render the `children` prop. 2)  In the `ProtectedRoutes` component replace `return <Navigate to='/' />` with `return <h1> Redirecting </h1>` and see if the heading gets rendered.